# Why does Firestore timestamp.toDate() add 4 hours to the date in cloud functions, but on the browser, it gets local time correctly?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions

I can't find any documentation anywhere that explains why on my local client in the browser, when I parse a `Timestamp` from Firestore, using `date.toDate()`, on my local client, it shows the date correctly. However, in my Cloud Functions, when I try to parse the same `Timestsamp` with `toDate()`, it shows the dates 4 hours ahead.

I've read that you can do something with UTC to remove that offset, but even when I've tried with MomentJS, it doesn't solve the problem.

Answer (score 2):

Firestore Timestamp and JavaScript Date objects don't have specific timestamps encoded in them.  If you just `console.log()` a date value, it will always render that date using the timezone configured on the local machine.  What you're seeing is that the server instance provided by Cloud Functions is configured for a different timezone than your local machine.

Momentjs will be able to render it for you in a timezone you choose, but you're probably just not using it correctly.